# 24t or 26t granny gear?

Tags: chainring, crankset

Getting a new crankset, decided on this one from Rivendell: http://www.rivbike.com/product-p/cr1.htm

Question: Should I keep the 24t granny or get them to swap it out for a 26t? I have some concerns that a 12t jump is going to be rather big. I'm guessing either way I will need a chain watcher, correct?

Drivetrain info: I'll be running this with a Sora triple front derailleur. The rest of my drive train is a 9spd Tiagra / Sora shifter set up.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the derailleur's spec sheet.

Comment: Spec says 50t max top ring, 20t capacity. So I guess 26t is the safe bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most manufacturers set maximum gear jump as 16t. I personally ride a 24/40t set and have no poblems with it with no additional equipment.
So from technical point view the difference isn't too significant and all that matters is what's more comfortable for you to ride.

Comment: hmm. I guess I'm not sure which one would be more comfortable. I haven't had a ring under 30t so I don't know. Maybe its just down to trial and error. But thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I have a 12 tooth jump on my granny gear from 30 to 42 and don't have any shifting problems using Shimano 2300 level equipment. A standard compact crank is 34/50 which is a 16 tooth jump, so 12 teeth really shouldn't create a lot of problems.

Comment: Y'know, I don't know why I didn't put that together. As I'm running a 50/34 and now I feel silly because the answer was right in front of me. *facepalm*  Thanks for the reply!